# ON TV Decoder Magazine Article/Circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, video, tv

Starting in the 1970s, there was a scrambled TV service transmitted over the air called "ON TV" in our region.  I think "Radio Electronics" magazine published an article about making a decoding circuit for it.

Looking back, I was curious how such a circuit worked, and wanted to know what issue the schematic might have been in so I can look up the issue and analyze it with a more experienced eye.

Comment: which region are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar article in Radio Electronics Jan 1981
https://archive.org/details/radio_electronics_1981-01/page/n35/mode/2up

Part 2
https://archive.org/details/radio_electronics_1981-02/page/n43/mode/2up
.

The later article (per GodJihyo) Feb 1984
https://archive.org/details/radio_electronics_1984-02/page/n43/mode/2up

A number of different decoding schemes were used in the day. Very popular was the version that hid the sync'ing pulse in the audio sub-channel where you had to decode it and reposition it back into the video signal.
.

Some additional ON TV information:

Wikipedia page - ON TV (TV network):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ON_TV_(TV_network)

YouTube - ON Subscription TV Decoder Box Teardown:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=PeeKnDpXahk

Comment: Yep, thank you; that first article is what I remember from childhood.  I even remember the girl on the page!

Comment: Oh, Bo !  Aside from that, I likely have a decoder that I built from those or very similar plans.

Answer (score 1):

That was probably the kind of scrambling where they change the sync levels in the transmitted signal so the TV receiver can’t lock onto them and you get a picture that won’t stabilize.

There is an article on a descrambler for such a system in the February 1984 issue of Radio Electronics.